# if value change restart after 24 hours mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using mySQL.

I creating something, if user click on button this change on database value from 1 to 0 (my value is daily and it's 0.)

When he clicked this he must wait next 24 hours to click this again.

I have created button and change on the database but this wait time and click again I don't know how.

I have in database:
value daily -- if it´s 0 you cannot click the button if 1 you can.
If somebody click value change back to 0 - COMPLETE
Create "event".."function" where he must wait 24 hours until he can again click.
And again, again,...

Thanks.

Here´s the code:

PHP

```
                                if($daily)
                                {
                                    echo "<form method='POST' action='./myphp.php'>
                                            <input value='AVAILABLE' type='submit'>
                                    </form>";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo "<form>
                                        <input value='AVAILABLE IN 24 HOURS'>
                                    </form>";                   
                                }
```

In the myphp.php

```
    $sql = "UPDATE points SET points = points + 15, daily = 0 WHERE steamid = '".$steamprofile['steamid']."'";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

In sql

```
I have value 0-1 - daily
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code so we can see what you have attempted and make corrections if required?

Comment: Added code, you can check it ;)

Comment: Did you consider using a timestamp column in the table to record when the event happens for that user?  When the user clicks again, compare the current time with the time in the table and if it is less than 24 hours, send message and prevent the code to write to database.  If more than 24 hours let it proceed and record new timestamp value.

Comment: Can you create this code? I don´t know how can I create that.